# How to make same link with many href using php?

Tags: php, html, css

I tried to find this answer in Search Engins but still not find it.
The example is like this :

```
<div class="article">
<img src="#" href="$link" /> <!--- same link --->
<h1><a href="$link">Head of Article</a></h1> <!-- same link ---> 
<p>Desc of article</p>
<a href="$link">Read</a> <!-- same link ---->
</div>

<!--example php --->
<?php
$link = "/article/blablabla.html" ;?>
```

I have tried to put the php in the top html and add echo but its not work. I want control the $link using the php . Some like that. So, I will not tried to write it one by one. Is it posibile? thanks!

Comment: replace href="$link" with href="<?php echo $link?>"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<!--example php --->
<?php
      $link = "/article/blablabla.html" ;
?>

<div class="article">
    <img src="#" href="<?php echo $link; ?>" /> <!--- same link --->
    <h1><a href="<?php echo $link; ?>">Head of Article</a></h1> <!-- same link ---> 
    <p>Desc of article</p>
    <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>">Read</a> <!-- same link ---->
</div>
```

Comment: thanks. it so simple!

Comment: Your are welcome. If this solved your issue please mark it as answered.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
      $link = "article/blablabla.html" ;
?>
```

change href to

```
href="<?php echo $link; ?>"
```